# Access Method in Separate Project, C#, VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a Form in a C# solution where I have a method that toggle's the visibility of an element on the form Sample Code:

```
namespace formplace.formlocation.Ui
{
 public class Form1: Mainform
  {
   ...
    public void activatepanel()
    {
     this.panel.visible = true; 
    }
  }
}
```

In a separate solution, I have a VB Solution that handles an event. I want to be able to call the method from the first solution in the second:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button.Click
  ...
  Call activatepanel somehow here
  ...
End Sub
```

Currently when I include Reference to C# Solution, Form1. (Suggestions here) Does not show the method activate panel. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to access the C# method from the Vb form?

Comment: Are you creating an instance of `Form1` or are you trying to access the method using the class name, i.e. trying to use the default instance? Show us the actual code you tried to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear (at least, for me) why you want to do this. The control you want to hide in the C# projects form is displayed at runtime so MAYBE you want to hide it from the VB program when both the programs are running, with some interprocess communication. 
Anyway, before you can access the method activatepanel() you need to have an instance of that class, either creating it or getting it in some other way.

Something like this:

```
Imports formplace.formlocation.Ui

....

  Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles Button.Click
      ...
      Dim csf As formplace.formlocation.Ui.Form1
      csf = New formplace.formlocation.Ui.Form1()
      csf.activatepanel()
      ...
    End Sub
```